# Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value when swap USDT to another token - python web3

Tags: web3.py, python

I am trying to swap USDT to another token on pancakeswap. When I use contract tokenToBuy as WBNB it works normally, but when I replace it with contract of USDT, it gives error ": ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value'}

How to fix this error? Please give me advice. Thank you

```
tokenToBuy = web3.toChecksumAddress("0x9fd87aefe02441b123c3c32466cd9db4c578618f") 
spend = web3.toChecksumAddress("0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955") 
#0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955 USDT contract


contract = web3.eth.contract(address=panRouterContractAddress, abi=panabi)
nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)
start = time.time()

pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
    int(minimum), 
    [spend, tokenToBuy],
    sender_address,
    (int(time.time()) + 10000) 
).buildTransaction({
    'from': sender_address,
    'value': web3.toWei(float(1), 'ether'),  
    'gas': 250000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei(float(gas), 'gwei'), 
    'nonce': nonce,
})
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure how your app works. But in my Python app, I need to mark the gas value. For example -> "gas": Wei(200000) so it knows how much I am willing to spend.

So in your case it would be 'gas': Wei(250000),   It's worth a shoot.

Comment: What is the balance of your sender account?

Comment: mine is 100 USDT, and BNB is enough to make transaction

Comment: @CaCa What code are you using? `swapExactETHForTokens` only works when paying with ETH/BNB, if you want to pay with an ERC-20 token you should call `swapExactTokensForTokens` or `swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`.

Comment: thanks @ismael , i have used wrong function

Answer (score 1):

```
def BuyUSDT(hedeftokenAddress, hedeftokenSymbol,walletAddress,private_key,gasAmount,gasPrice,snipeBNBAmount):
    if(hedeftokenAddress != None):
        tokenToBuy = web3.toChecksumAddress(hedeftokenAddress)
        #tokenToBuy2 = web3.toChecksumAddress(tokenAddress)
        spend = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c")  #wbnb contract address
        token2=web3.toChecksumAddress("0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955")
        contract = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeSwapRouterAddress, abi=pancakeABI)
        # contractpancake = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeSwapRouterAddress, abi=pancakeABI)
        # amount_out = contractpancake.functions.getAmountsOut(int(snipeBNBAmount*1e18), [spend,tokenToBuy]).call()[-1]
        # min_tokens = int(amount_out * (1 - (40 / 100)))
        #snipeBNBAmounttoBUSD= snipeBNBAmount*400
        pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            0, # Set to 0 or specify min number of tokens - setting to 0 just buys X amount of token at its current price for whatever BNB specified
            [spend,token2,tokenToBuy],
            walletAddress,
            (int(time.time()) + transactionRevertTime)
            ).buildTransaction({
                'from': walletAddress,
                'value': web3.toWei(float(snipeBNBAmount), 'ether'), #This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from
                'gas': gasAmount,
                'gasPrice': web3.toWei(gasPrice,'gwei'),
                'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress),
                })


        signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key)
        tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction) #BUY THE TOKEN
        
        txHash = str(web3.toHex(tx_token))
        
        #TOKEN IS BOUGHT

        checkTransactionSuccessURL = "https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=transaction&action=gettxreceiptstatus&txhash=" + txHash + "&apikey=" + bscScanAPIKey
        checkTransactionRequest = requests.get(url = checkTransactionSuccessURL)
        txResult = checkTransactionRequest.json()['status']
        # except:
        #     print(style.RED + currentTimeStamp + " 1.Hesap BUSD - Transaction failed.")
        #     print("") # line break: move onto scanning for next token
    
        try: 
            if(txResult == "1"):
                print(style.GREEN + currentTimeStamp + " 1.Hesap USDT Successfully bought $" + hedeftokenSymbol + " for " + style.BLUE + str(snipeBNBAmount) + style.GREEN + " BNB - TX ID: ", txHash)
                with open('{}\\transferlerV2.txt'.format(ROOT_PATH),'a', encoding='utf8') as conf:
                    conf.writelines(currentTimeStamp + "  " + " 1.Hesap USDT - TX ID: " + txHash)
            else:
                print(style.RED + currentTimeStamp + " 1.Hesap USDT - Alındı ama BSC FAİL ile döndü.")
        except:
            print(style.RED + currentTimeStamp + " 1.Hesap USDT - Transaction failed: likely not enough gas.")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).